# Excel - Variable number of leading zeros in variable length numbers?

Tags: excel, formatting, numbers, zero

The format of our member numbers has changed several times over the years, such that 00008, 9538, 746, 0746, 00746, 100125, and various other permutations are valid, unique and need to be retained. Exporting from our database into the custom Excel template needed for a mass update strips the leading zeros, such that 00746 and 0746 are all truncated to 746.

Inserting the apostrophe trick, or formatting as text, does not work in our case, since the data seems to be already altered by the time we open it in Excel. Formatting as zip won't work since we have valid numbers less than five digits in length that cannot have zeros added to them. And I am not having any luck with "custom" formatting as that seems to require either adding the same number of leading zeros to a number, or adding enough zeros to every number to make them all the same length.

Any clues? I wish there was some way to set Excel to just take what it's given and leave it alone, but that does not seem to be the case! I would appreciate any suggestions or advice. Thank you all very much in advance!

UPDATE - thanks everybody for your help! Here are some more specifics. We are using a 3rd party membership management app -- we cannot access the database directly, we need to use their "query builder" tool to get the data we want to mass update. Then we export using their "template" format, which is called XLSX but there must be something going on behind the scenes, because if we try to import a regular old Excel, we get an error. Only their template works.

The data is formatted okay in the database, because all of the numbers show correctly in the web-based management tool. Also, if I export to CSV, save it as a .txt and import it into Excel, the numbers show fine.

What I have done is similar to ooo's explanation below -- I exported the template with the incorrect numbers, then exported as CSV/txt, and copied / pasted THOSE numbers into the template and re-imported. I did not get an error, which is something I guess, but I will not be able to find out if it was successful until after midnight!  :-(

Comment: How is the data coming out of the database? Are you exporting to a file and then opening that?

Comment: There is definitely nothing you can do once your data is in Excel.  You will have to either export your data differently, or modify the data *in your database* before exporting it.  We'll be able to give more specific suggestions when you tell us more about your current export process.

Comment: Hello dash and John Y, I hope I clarified what is happening a little bit. Let me know if you need more specifics! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Typical 3rd party companies, they let you put data in but never let you get what you need out unless it's 1 record at a time or a 'Custom' report :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the membership number once more to M0000000000012345 - assuming you're popular :)

Comment: LOL! I wish! We found that by adding an "a" or "_" or some other character at the end of the member number works. It guess Excel sees that as text, so the leading zeros are all left alone. We'd hate to do that, as it would mean printing up new member cards and all, but if your method does not work out for us, we might have to. I will give you an update first thing tomorrow AM! Thanks!

Comment: It did indeed! Worked like a charm in fact. Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Excellent!  (The stuff I was going to suggest if it didn't work would have been much harder to explain.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the data is not corrupt in the database, then try and export from the database to a csv or text file.

The following can then be done to ensure the import is formatted correctly

Text file with comma delimiter:

[image]

In Excel Data/From text and selected Delimited, then next

[image]

[image]

In step 3 of the import wizard. For each column/field you want as text, highlight the column and select Text

[image]

The data should then be placed as text and retain leading zeros.

[image]

Again, all of this assumes the database contains non-corrupt data and you are able to export a simple text or csv file. It also assumes you have Excel 2010 but it can be done with minor variation across all versions.

Comment: ooo, I think we are on the same page more or less. I am using your exact steps, and pasting the properly formatted numbers into the special template we need to use to do a mass update. The updates do not get processed until midnight, so I will see what happens with the test I did, using your method, and I will let you know first thing tomorrow! I really appreciate your help though, those screenshots are awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you turn on the macro recorder when doing those steps you can run the macro each time rather than doing it manually. Useful if there are lots of fields.

Comment: I have to give this an upvote for the screenshots if nothing else.  Really great job on the clarity and user-friendliness of the answer.  Now, we just have to hope that the software daltec is saddled with accepts it.

Comment: I agree John Y, it was really something else! I upvoted it just now too. I will definitely check to see what happened, first thing tomorrow!

Comment: I am pleased to announce that your solution worked like a charm! I double checked the records, even those where I had deliberately introduced some errors as a control, and everything went without a hitch. In fact, I re-exported the changed records, to make sure the member numbers were still correct, and everything went great. Thank you SO much, this is going to be a great help for us! I really appreciate your taking the time, and in fact if you do not mind, I'd like to forward your screenshots to my colleagues to make sure we are all using the correct method.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. It's fine to forward the screenshots; in fact you don't really need to ask permission as everything on this site is intended for public consumption.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness, ooo, and thank you again for your help. I've gotten some really good help on ColdFusion questions as well -- one day I will know enough to be able to answer questions, myself!  :-)  Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, @ooo's answer works for you.  I'm providing another answer mainly for informational purposes, and don't feel like dealing with the constraints on comments.

One thing to understand is that Excel is very aggressive about treating "numeric-looking" data as actual numbers.  If you were to open the CSV by double-clicking and letting Excel do its thing (rather than using ooo's careful procedure), those numbers would still have come up as numbers (no leading zeros).  As you've found, one way to counteract this is to append clearly nonnumeric characters onto your data (before Excel gets its grubby hands on it), to *really convince* Excel that what it's dealing with is text.

Now, if the thing that uploads to their software is a file ending in `.xlsx`, then most likely it *is* the current Excel format (a compressed XML document, used by Excel 2007 and later).  I suppose by "regular old Excel" you mean `.xls` (which still works with the newer Excels in "compatibility mode").

So in case what you've tried so far doesn't work, there are still avenues to explore before resorting to appending characters to the end of your data.  (I'll update this answer as needed.)

Comment: Hi John Y, that makes a lot of sense when I take the time to sit down and think about it. And you are 100% correct, it's almost like you need to trick Excel before bringing the data in. We also found that both xlsx and xls work, but csv or anything else does not. And, we cannot create our own XLSX, it *must* use their "template" file or we will get an error. Even if it looks exactly the same, columns are named the same, and so on. Whatever! ooo's solution is a couple of extra steps, but man is it going to save us some time!

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with the apostrophe.
You'll need to store your numbers in excel as text at the time they are added to the file.

What are you using to create the original excel file / export from database?
This will likely be where your focus needs to be regarding your export.

For example one approach is that you could potentially modify the database export to include the `'` symbol prefix before the numbers so that excel will know to display them as text.

Comment: Hi Gimp, I updated my original question above. We're using a 3rd-party system that we cannot edit or modify. However, it does preserve the data -- the numbers are fine if we export as XML or CSV as .txt. It's only when we open in Excel that we have the problem. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I use the formula `=text(cell,"# of zeros of the field")` to add preceding zeros.

Example, Cell `C2` has *12345* and I need it to be *10* characters long.  I would put `=text(c2,"0000000000")`.

The result will be *0000012345*.